# Error in solve.default(tmp, v) : system is computationally singular

Tags: r, bioconductor

I recently installed TurboNorm package and trying to use it. They have provided an example file to run the sample analysis. To quote the manual.

> The pspline() - function can be used for normalization of two-colour
>   microarray data. The data input is either an object of type RGList as
>   dened in the package limma or an object of type MarrayRaw dened in
>   the package marray. The pspline()-function recognizes the type of the
>   object and returns the normalized object of the same type, i.e.
>   MAList.

I have read my data (8 arrays) using the package limma using the command

```
RG <- read.maimages(targets$FileName, source="agilent")
```

The resulting object is of type RGList so is the test file provided in the package.

When I run the command

```
x <- pspline(methylation, showArrays=2, pch=20, col="grey")
```

it works fine, but when I run

```
x <- pspline(RG, showArrays=2, pch=20, col="grey")
```

it throws an error

```
Error in solve.default(tmp, v) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 9.32764e-19
```

The limma package function to normalize the data seems to work fine.

Thank you.

Comment: I installed the same package on another machine running Ubuntu, now the error message is 
> 
Error in rep(0, n + 1) : invalid 'times' argument

Comment: Have you asked the person returned by the function `packageMaintainer("TurboNorm")`?